# Cox Proportional Hazards Assumptions - Simplest Tests in R

Tags: cox-model, assumptions

I have no stats background, and have been looking into Cox models.

$$ h(t) = h_0(t)e^{\beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + ...}$$

(Where $h$ is an individual hazard function, $h_0$ is the baseline hazard function, $x$ is some descriptor of an individual and $\beta$ is a weight on that descriptor.)

I understand that there are three assumptions needed for the model to be valid.

1. The model must be multiplicative - the link between $h(t)$ and $h_0(t)$ must be of the form $h(t) = ah_0(t)$.
2. Proportional hazards must hold - the ratio of the hazards of two individuals must be constant, i.e. $\beta$ must not be a function of $t$.
3. The relationship between $h$ and $h_0$ for a specific $t$ must be log-linear with respect to any $x$. (i.e. $ log(h(t)) = log(h_0(t))+{\beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + ...}$. 
   (I understand that rather than throwing the model out, this can be fixed by converting that particular exponent to $\beta f(x)$.)

What are the simplest ways to test these assumptions in R?

Also, how do I find out which $f(x)$ to use and test if that model is a better fit?

Thanks for any help,

Stephanie
(Edited for accuracy.)

Comment: To begin with, you should peruse the column of linked questions to the right --> under **Related**. Several of the questions there relate to testing Cox assumptions (mostly the proportional hazard assumption).